# Java regex spot substring starting with specific chars following by some digits

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find a regex pattern like 'ABCxxxxx' (x is digit and as an example we have 5 x) to spot any similar substrings in another string.

with the above regex

```
ABC12345 or
ABC09090 or
ABC 54321 etc.
```

are all match.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks,

It still does not work! Thats what I have tried base on your replies:
my text is

```
Fwd: Fwd: kam rran 2323242 ojdwohejf ABC12345 dewfwe
```

The code is:

```
String regex = "ABC\\s*\\d{5}";

java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(
                 regex, 
                 java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE
);

Matcher m = pattern.matcher(subject);

if (m.find()) {
   this.setThat(m.group());
}
```

But it does not pass the if condition!!!!

Comment: just to add, ABC part is fixed.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I want it to be spotted anywhere in the string even in forms like

Comment: [ABC12345] or {ABC12312} or (ABC98763)

Comment: Check out this demo : http://fiddle.re/dkz5

Comment: Another demo based on the code in the question : http://ideone.com/UoCOA0

Comment: For the future reference can anyone let me know why did i get 2 vote down? Just want to improve my way

Answer (score 3):

You can try this regex:

```
ABC\s*\d{5}
```

- `ABC`   => matches the sequence of letters ABC
- `\s*`   => matches one or more blank characters
- `\d{5}` => matches 5 digits

Note: Don't forget to escape '\' with a '\' in your code.

Answer (score 2):

For `ABC` followed by any number of digits:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("ABC\\s*\\d+");
```

or for specifically 5 digits:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("ABC\\s*\\d{5}");
```

Comment: A space can appear between ABC and digits

Answer (score 1):

This regex `"ABC[0-9]{5}"` should help. It will match for prefix as "ABC" followed by any numerals.

You may want to use `"ABC[0-9]+"` for any number of numerals after `ABC`.